# не работает vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Как я понимаю конфликт имён свойств в data и validations не подскажить как указать правильно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не указаны правила валидации.
Добавьте в компонент v-text-field:

```
:rules="[rules.required, rules.email]"
```

Затем добавьте в data следующее:

```
rules: {
   required: value => !!value || 'Обязательно для заполнения.',
   email: value => {
     const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
     return pattern.test(value) || 'Неверное имя e-mail адреса.'
   },
},
```

Вся информация о валидации компонента v-text-field может быть найдена в соответствующем разделе документации vuetify:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/